# Enable RemoteFX USB redirection via Registry

Tags: group-policy, windows-registry, windows-terminal-services, remotefx

I am trying to enable RemoteFX USB redirection on our thin clients which are not domain joined.

Currently, if I use local group policy editor on one of the devices, and set the policy to enabled for users and admins, the redirection works as expected.

I have found that the registry equivalent of this policy, is:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\Client
```

With a value of fUsbRedirectionEnableMode. If you set this to 2, that should be the same as enabling the policy. I have also proved using procmon that this is the value that gpedit modifies when enabling the policy.

When doing it via the registry however and not via the policy editor, the redirection does not get enabled.

Is there some other registry entry that would need to be modified in order to enable this without having to touch the group policy editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found a utility (LGPO.exe), which can be used to export GPO settings, and import them to another machine.

We are now able to script the usage of this utility to export a working set of policies from one device, and successfully import to another.